Prevent/Disable close option in Electron app
I am trying to prevent the user from closing the Electron application. In my case user is using Alt + spacebar combination and by doing so a menu will appear in which we have a close option. Please refer the image attached with comment.
I want to disable Alt + spacebar option, if that is not possible, I want to disable close option in the popup menu.
I tried following code, but it is not working for me:
if ((input.alt && input.code === 'Space') || (input.alt && input.key === ' ')) {
event.preventDefault();
}

if ((input.key === 'Alt' && input.code === 'Space') || (input.key === 'Alt' && input.key === ' ')) {
event.preventDefault();
}


You can disable predefined keyboard shortcuts (or accelerators) with the globalShortcut module.
So if you want to unregister the alt+space shortcut, you can do so using this method:
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    globalShortcut.unregister('Alt+Space')
})    

The globalShortcut module cannot be called before the ready event of the app.

Thanks for the suggestion. But if I use the electron app is reloading.

Where are you adding that line? It can't be called before the ready event of the app

I have added it in the ready event only. Now app is not reloading, but I am still able to see the popup for closing the application.
